# Custom, external Rules Engine for setting object properties on a large dataset

Tags: c#, vb.net, expression, workflow-foundation-4, rule-engine

I know this isn't a direct coding question, but I'm hoping someone can point me in the right direction and save me from spending even more insane amounts of time on researching something they already know the answer to...

I'm writing a program in C# (or VB) that will require a rules engine to calculate a set of dynamic properties on a set of objects retrieved from a DB **based upon rules that are external to the program**.

So, for example, suppose I have a list of, say, 250,000 objects / records returned from a DB. 
Each of which has 20 set properties / values that I need to run through a rules engine to calculate a further 15 dynamic properties (per object).

Each of those 15 dynamic properties will:

1. Use complex logic such as `If / Then`, `Between x and y`, `BeginsWith()`, etc.
2. Be based upon some of the other 20 original / 14 dynamically created properties (so the program would need to order the calculations if, say, `DynamicPropertyA` was reliant on the value obtained for `DynamicPropertyB`, then `DynamicPropertyB` would have to be calculated first)

to obtain its value.

And, what I'm looking for, is not to hard-code these rules into the program, but, rather, to have them in a file / table separate from the program that is parsed in at run-time, so any rule updates would not require re-coding / re-compilation.

Also, of course, since this would be run over a large dataset, it would be GREATLY preferred that the rules are compiled once at the start rather than re-processed on a record-by-record basis.

I've looked into [Windows Workflow Rules engine](http://www.richard-banks.org/2007/08/how-to-use-windows-workflow-rules.html) and other tools such as [C# Expression Evaluator](https://csharpeval.codeplex.com/), but was wondering if anyone here has done something similar / has any experience with these / any other library that can offer any help or point me in the right direction.

THANKS!!!